# JavaFX TreeTableView calculating scrollbar wrong

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have problems with my JavaFX TreeTableView. In one case, I have > 100 columns and here the problem is worst. I am using JDK 8u121x64.

When having many columns, the scrollbar is calculated wrong and **cutting of the last column**. Here is a SSCCE

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeTableViewScroll extends Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final Scene scene = createScene();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree Table View Scroll");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Scene createScene() {
        final VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        vBox.setSpacing(5);

        final TreeTableView<String> resultsTable = new TreeTableView<>();
        resultsTable.setShowRoot(false);
        final TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<>();
        resultsTable.setRoot(rootItem);

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            final TreeTableColumn<String, String> dummyColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Long Column name " + i);
            resultsTable.getColumns().add(dummyColumn);
        }

        final TreeTableColumn<String, String> nameColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Name_very long column text");
        resultsTable.getColumns().add(nameColumn);

        vBox.getChildren().setAll(resultsTable);
        VBox.setVgrow(resultsTable, Priority.ALWAYS);
        vBox.setPrefSize(800, 600);

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            final TreeItem<String> newItem = new TreeItem<>("Text " + i);
            rootItem.getChildren().add(newItem);
            newItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>("Text " + i));
        }

        return new Scene(vBox);
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Or is this a framework bug? And if, where do I file the bug?

[image: Screenshot of the]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Issue in JDK8, where as i could see the expected result in JDK9 ea build
You should file issue with java - http://bugreport.java.com/submit_intro.do

[image]

Comment: Sure, do you know an easy why to get the J9 ea on my windows system (without "installing" it, which would override the system java)

Comment: @Rainer Presumably, if it's been fixed in Java 9, then it's already been filed (and, well, fixed). So you should at a minimum search for an existing bug report before filing. (It's unlikely any fixes will be backported to Java 8, so it might not be worth filing this at this stage.)

Comment: @James_D you were right - but I could not find the bug - I really searched the bug database. So here is the duplicate -.- JDK-8179061

Comment: No JDK-8179061 is the one which have have filed yesterday.  Infact duplicate bug exist https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8163943. JDK-8179061 has not been closed yet, lets wait and see if it gets backported to 8.